# Notification when there is an update

Tags: android, ios, notifications, google-play, app-store

I have been looking for a while to send a message to a user when there is a new version of the app is released. When I upload a new version to the Appstore or GooglePlay a message should appear when the user opens the app, but does not have the latest version that will allow user to easily update the app.

Do you guys have any solution for this? It`s for IOS and android.

Comment: if your last build  does not have  app update code than you can't force user to update their app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to approach that problem.

1. Send remote notification for each user about new version being available. Problem with this solution is you have to get user's permission first, but it will be definitely the most convenient one to use.
2. In-App updates:

   For Android: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates

   For iOS: you will have to build similar logic on your own. You will need a server-side logic - just a file exposing latest version string. Then on iOS when user is launching the application, you can compare users version with that file - and if it's different, show a custom popup telling user there is a new version available and link to AppStore.

   Problem here is that user has to launch the old version - which will not give you similar results as remote notifications, which will be shown without user opening the application.

I think the best solution would be to do both and cover all cases. Remote notifications will be definitely nicer way to do that for users that allows you to do so, rest of the users will be notified inside application itself. Just make sure to not notify user about update each time they open the application if they don't update it - best approach here will be to do it once per version maybe or even better make your version file to define it update is something really crucial and should trigger a popup.

Comment: Just what i need perfect description.

Comment: @aaronversfeld good luck ! and remember about remote notifications, if you have often updates - consider to not spam user too much - as they may get angry about it and disable remote notifications which will be painful for you to use them for anything else. It's wise to have maybe a special group for "udpate" notifications, so user can just disable those.

Comment: Yes thats something i was thinking of how i supposed to do that but i have some ideas for that. thanks for the help!